# Move parent class object to child class

Tags: php, oop

I have two classes:

```
class A {...}
class B extends A {...}
```

Now I have this object

```
$object = new A();
```

Now I want this object to be instance from B(so that I can use '$this' inside B class.
Because I have many objects from class A. for each I have to choose which sub class I need for it. (B or C or even D)

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, you can't access fields of B class, if you use A class constructor.